# Action Sheet space between title and message?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

Currently trying to create an action sheet that contains some space between the title and the message.

Here's what my action sheet currently looks like:

[image]

Here is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Disregard the random blue circle under in the "Stop Following" button in the second picture. I'm simply trying to achieve the space between the title and the message without having to create a custom Action Sheet. Is this achievable? And if so, how?

Comment: Not sure if it works but try adding some newlines at the end of the title or start of the message.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid...Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add line break **\n** on the message should help:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Stop Following", message: "\n\n\nYou'll stop receiving activity", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
```

[image]

Comment: You just copied @rmaddy comments as your answer

Comment: He didn't point how to add new line. Also if so no one should answer this question?

Comment: `newlines` is the word already mentioned in the comments. The Questioner accepted that in comments too.

Comment: Last comment: 1) **\n** wan't mentioned. 2) Usually this should be the typical way to try.  3) No copy. 4) If there are 100 comments without a answer someone can still answer. 5) farewell.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari There's nothing wrong with someone converting a comment into a proper answer as long as the answer is useful (which this one is).